# How do I create a datetime in Python from milliseconds?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I create a datetime in Python from milliseconds? I can create a similar `Date` object in Java by [`java.util.Date(milliseconds)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: related since seconds to milliseconds is just a factor: [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3682748/10197418)

Answer (score 379, accepted):

Just convert it to timestamp

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000.0)
```

Comment: A note -- in Python 3, (/) will perform floating-point division. To perform integral division, use (//).

Comment: Don't you actually want float division anyway? Otherwise you're losing any precision below 1 second (held in the fractional part of the timestamp).  Better to use ms/1000.0 with no truncation.

Comment: Not all platforms support fractional timestamps -- better to stick with POSIX's integers.

Comment: Surely datetime always supports it though?  If we've got sub-second precision, it seems wrong to throw it away.  If we don't there's no harm done - we just retain that original precision.

Comment: To keep the precision without using floats, you can also do: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ms//1000).replace(microsecond=ms%1000*1000)`

Comment: another problem with this solution: "fromtimestamp() may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C localtime() or gmtime() functions. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038."  - how long is your code expected to last???

Comment: It gives local time. How can I get gmt

Comment: WHY it gives an exception in the years before 1970? Aren't those years as well

Answer (score 20):

What about this?  I presume it can be counted on to handle dates before 1970 and after 2038.

```py
target_datetime_ms = 200000 # or whatever
base_datetime = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
delta = datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 0, target_datetime_ms)
target_datetime = base_datetime + delta
```

as mentioned in the Python standard lib:

> fromtimestamp() may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out of the
> range of values supported by the platform C localtime() or gmtime()
> functions. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970
> through 2038.

Very obviously, this can be done in one line:

```
target_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=target_dt_ms)
```

... not only was this obvious from my answer, but the 2015 comment by jfs is also highly misleading, because it calls the variable `utc_time`.

Er no: it's not "time", it's `datetime`, and it's most definitely NOT *UTC*. The `datetime` with which we're concerned here is a "timezone-naive" `datetime`, as opposed to a **timezone-aware** `datetime`. Therefore definitely NOT UTC.

Search on this if you're not familiar with the issue.

Comment: you could use `utc_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=millis)`

Comment: @jfs your comment is misleading, and also obvious from my question. Please read my comments about your comment and then delete your comment.

Comment: what do you think would be the result of `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)`?

Answer (score 20):

Converting millis to datetime (UTC):

```
import datetime
time_in_millis = 1596542285000
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_in_millis / 1000.0, tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: would be my accepted answer since Java's Date also refers to UTC by default (vs. Python's naive datetime / tz not set refers to *local time*).

Answer (score 17):

```
import pandas as pd

Date_Time = pd.to_datetime(df.NameOfColumn, unit='ms')
```

Answer (score 13):

Bit heavy because of using pandas but works:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(msec_from_java, unit='ms').to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: this is efficient for converting en masse and returns a `Series` object