# Converting unix timestamp string to readable date

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp, strftime

I have a string representing a unix timestamp (i.e. "1284101485") in Python, and I'd like to convert it to a readable date. When I use `time.strftime`, I get a `TypeError`:

```python
>>>import time
>>>print time.strftime("%B %d %Y", "1284101485")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str
```

Comment: link to question for converting back too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19801727/3273031

Answer (score 1575):

Use `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = int('1284101485')

# if you encounter a "year is out of range" error the timestamp
# may be in milliseconds, try `ts /= 1000` in that case
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: `.fromtimestamp()` might fail for past dates if a local timezone had different utc offset. You need a historic timezone database such as provided by `pytz` module (or your OS). Or just work in UTC and use `.utcfromtimestamp()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You've mentioned this might fail in a couple of comments - please could you elaborate as to why it would fail for a past dates/times? (Judging by the upvotes, many people both agree with you and see this as straightforward) Surely any unix timestamp has a simple equivalent date/time?

Comment: @davidhood2 take a system where python has no access to [the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (Windows), set your local timezone to a timezone that had a different UTC offset in the past (e.g. Europe/Moscow), call fromtimestamp() with timestamps from the past (2011-). Compare the results with values computed using `pytz`. If it is unclear; ask  a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @davidhood2: I've posted [my own answer that demonstrates the `pytz` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40769643/4279).

Comment: An import point is this takes a timestamp in seconds since the epoch; if you have milliseconds you have to divide by 1000 as I just found out.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `strftime` over `"{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}".format(dateobj)`?

Comment: According to Python documentation `__format__()` is same as `strftime()` but I simply prefer `strftime()`.

Comment: If you are getting `ValueError: year VALUE is out of range`, that means you are working with milliseconds(Unix timestamp is 13 digits). The above function works only if Unix timestamp in seconds. 

If you are working with milliseconds, divide that value by 1000.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/31548132/2960555

Comment: What if I want to include milliseconds?

Comment: @User pass a float e.g., if you have `1234` milliseconds then pass `1.234` seconds (it is easy to divide by 1000 on the decimal system: just move the decimal dot 3 positions to the left).

Comment: or just `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1398385815)`

Comment: `.utcfromtimestamp()` is deprecated and `.fromtimestamp()` should be used instead

Answer (score 329):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1172969203.1)
datetime.datetime(2007, 3, 4, 0, 46, 43, 100000)
```

Taken from http://seehuhn.de/pages/pdate

Comment: This method return an datetime.datetime object. This can be printed as it has the magic __str__() method included.

Also check out the [best comment][1], so `print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time_value)` will make it human-readable.


    [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date#comment30046351_3682808

Answer (score 197):

The most voted answer suggests using fromtimestamp which is error prone since it uses the local timezone. To avoid issues a better approach is to use UTC:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(posix_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Where posix_time is the Posix epoch time you want to convert

Comment: import datetime, pytz    datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

Comment: beware, unix time might be different from posix time in (rare) cases e.g., `TZ=right/UTC date` vs. `TZ=UTC date` is `Mon  7 Sep 15:58:05 UTC 2020` vs. `Mon  7 Sep 15:58:32 UTC 2020` (the difference may change depending on the number of leap seconds)

Comment: `ValueError: year 53085 is out of range`

Comment: @alper In such cases, likely one has a timestamp in milliseconds; try dividing by 1000. Or by 1000000 if the timestamp is in microseconds.

Comment: What exactly does "it uses the local timezone" mean? Does it assume that the timestamp refers to the number of seconds elapsed since 1/1/70 in the local timezone? Or does it correctly assume the timestamp is the number of seconds since 1/1/70 in UTC, and then express the resulting date/time in the local timezone?

Answer (score 93):

There are two parts:

1. Convert the unix timestamp ("seconds since epoch") to the local time
2. Display the local time in the desired format.

A portable way to get the local time that works even if the local time zone had a different utc offset in the past and python has no access to the tz database is to use a `pytz` timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal  # $ pip install tzlocal

unix_timestamp = float("1284101485")
local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone() # get pytz timezone
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp, local_timezone)
```

To display it, you could use any time format that is supported by your system e.g.:

```
print(local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z (%Z)"))
print(local_time.strftime("%B %d %Y"))  # print date in your format
```

---

If you do not need a local time, to get a readable UTC time instead:

```
utc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
print(utc_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00 (UTC)"))
```

---

If you don't care about the timezone issues that might affect *what date is returned* or if python has access to the tz database on your system:

```
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
print(local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

On Python 3, you could get a timezone-aware datetime using only stdlib (the UTC offset may be wrong if python has no access to the tz database on your system e.g., on Windows):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp, timezone.utc)
local_time = utc_time.astimezone()
print(local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z (%Z)"))
```

Functions from the `time` module are thin wrappers around the corresponding C API and therefore they may be less portable than the corresponding `datetime` methods otherwise you could use them too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

unix_timestamp  = int("1284101485")
utc_time = time.gmtime(unix_timestamp)
local_time = time.localtime(unix_timestamp)
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", local_time)) 
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00 (UTC)", utc_time))
```

Comment: It should be the most voted answer if you care about local time.

Comment: if you get ValueError: year xxx is out of range error divide your timestamp to /1000 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31548402/1428241

Comment: @jfs is there a similar method to convert back from date-time string back to the Unix timestamp?

Comment: @ENV: once you've parsed your input time string into an aware datetime object, just call its `.timestamp()` method. How to convert the time string depends on its format -- it is ambiguous in the general case but there are many solution for various cases.

Answer (score 92):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(int("1284101485"))
'Fri Sep 10 16:51:25 2010'
>>> time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int("1284101485")))
'09/10/10 16:51'
```

Comment: `time.ctime()` and `time.localtime()` might fail for past dates if a local timezone had different utc offset. You need a historic timezone database such as provided by `pytz` module (or your OS). Or just work in UTC and use `time.gmtime()`. `datetime` might provide wider date range so `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` could be used instead of `time` functions.

Comment: @John La Rooy is there a similar method to convert back from date-time string back to the Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 80):

In Python 3.6+:

```
import datetime

timestamp = 1642445213
value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(f"{value:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}")
```

#### Output (local time)

```
2022-01-17 20:46:53
```

#### Explanation

- Line #1: Import [datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html).
- Line #2: Unix time which is [seconds since 1970-01-01](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).
- Line #3: Converts this to a unix time object, check with: `type(value)`
- Line #4: Prints in the [same format as strp](https://strftime.org/). Local time. To print in UTC see example below.

#### Bonus

To save the date to a string then print it, use this:

```
my_date = f"{value:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"
print(my_date)
```

To output in UTC:

```
value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
# 2022-01-17 18:50:52
```

Comment: Great answer, but whish you showed how you could save the date to a string, and not just print it: value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: @bjornasm Sure, updated answer with a similar method to achieve this.

Comment: f-strings are specific to Python v3.6+ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51262245/4442148

Comment: The output is ***not UTC*** but local time, unless you set the `tz` argument in `fromtimestamp`, e.g. to `datetime.timezone.utc`.

Comment: @MrFruppes Correct. Edited answer on 2022-01-17 to fix this.

Answer (score 45):

Other than using **time/datetime** package, **pandas** can also be used to solve the same problem.Here is how we can use **pandas** to convert **timestamp** to **readable date**:

Timestamps can be in two formats:

1. 13 digits(milliseconds) -
   To convert **milliseconds** to date, use:

   ```
   import pandas
   result_ms=pandas.to_datetime('1493530261000',unit='ms')
   str(result_ms)

   Output: '2017-04-30 05:31:01'
   ```
2. 10 digits(seconds) -
   To convert **seconds** to date, use:

   ```
   import pandas
   result_s=pandas.to_datetime('1493530261',unit='s')
   str(result_s)

   Output: '2017-04-30 05:31:01'
   ```

Answer (score 38):

For a human readable timestamp from a UNIX timestamp, I have used this in scripts before:

```
import os, datetime

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(os.path.getmtime("FILE"))).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Output:

'December 26, 2012'

Comment: I didn't need the float. just this : datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getmtime('file')).strftime("%B %d, %Y")

Answer (score 29):

You can convert the current time like this

```
t=datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2012-03-07'
```

To convert a date in string to different formats.

```
import datetime,time

def createDateObject(str_date,strFormat="%Y-%m-%d"):    
    timeStamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(str_date,strFormat))
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeStamp)

def FormatDate(objectDate,strFormat="%Y-%m-%d"):
    return objectDate.strftime(strFormat)

Usage
=====
o=createDateObject('2013-03-03')
print FormatDate(o,'%d-%m-%Y')

Output 03-03-2013
```

Answer (score 24):

```python
timestamp ="124542124"
value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
exct_time = value.strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Get the readable date from timestamp with time also, also you can change the format of the date.

Comment: What does this answer add to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21578729/8254699) answer?

Comment: Please add a warning related to issue of local timezone assumption. Best practices in programming is to store timestamps as UTC times instead of local timestamps. But this example above will return the wrong time if the local timezone is not UTC.

Answer (score 12):

Note that `utcfromtimestamp` can lead to [unexpected results](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) since it returns a naive datetime object. Python treats naive datetime as *local time* - while UNIX time refers to UTC.

This ambiguity can be avoided by setting the `tz` argument in `fromtimestamp`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dtobj = datetime.fromtimestamp(1284101485, timezone.utc)

>>> print(repr(dtobj))
datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 10, 6, 51, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Now you can format to string, e.g. an ISO8601 compliant format:

```
>>> print(dtobj.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z'))
2010-09-10T06:51:25.000Z
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the following codes, I hope it will solve your problem.

```
import datetime as dt

print(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1284101485")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: add an explanation re, why this code will solve the problem to improve your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`datetime.strftime(format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime
unixtime = int('1284101485')

# Print with local time
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

# Print with UTC time
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unixtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

- [`datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp): Return the local date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by `time.time()`.
- [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp): Return the UTC datetime corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, with tzinfo None. (The resulting object is naive.)

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime
temp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1386181800).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print temp
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way that this can be done using gmtime and format function;

```
from time import gmtime
print('{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}'.format(*gmtime(1538654264.703337)))
```

Output: `2018-10-4 11:57:44`

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with a dataframe and **do not** want the `series cannot be converted to class int` error. Use the code below.

```
new_df= pd.to_datetime(df_new['time'], unit='s')
```

Answer (score 1):

i just successfully used:

```
>>> type(tstamp)
pandas.tslib.Timestamp
>>> newDt = tstamp.date()
>>> type(newDt)
datetime.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_date_string = date_converter.timestamp_to_string(1284101485, "%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: Every programming has it's own date and time converters. One should never have to use mods/frameworks for this

Comment: `strptime` and `strftime` isn't intuitive... And even not readable... But I understand and respect your opinion

Comment: That one should "never have to use" is wrong. It depends on the language and the quality of the built-in libs.

Javascript has moments.js and Java had Joda time which both are more popular than the respective built-in date and time conversion utils (so much that Joda time later influenced Java 8's updated standard libs).

That said, unless the question calls for nice third-party libraries, it's preferable to give an answer based on the standard library.

Comment: I stand corrected @NikosVentouras. I've just had the "JS Date in IE behaves differently" issue for the first time. So I ended up using moment.js

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty one liner:

```
'-'.join(str(x) for x in list(tuple(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())[:6]))
```

'2013-5-5-1-9-43'

Comment: Or more concisely: '-'.join(map(str, datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()[:6]))

Comment: @JelleZijlstra Eh, I much prefer the generator expression over map.

Comment: What kind of date format is '2013-5-5-1-9-43' ? I've never seen this format anywhere as a valid representation of a date/time.

Comment: can you elaborate on what qualifies this as an invalid representation @madoki ? do you mean nonstandard? The primary advantage it has over most other answers is the ability to include it in a file or directory path, as spaces and colons are not in the set of standard unix directory characters. see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/458001/209246

Answer (score 0):

I used [pytz](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/) to create a function that converts the UNIX date and time to Helsinki timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
    
def convert_date_time(unix_date,unix_time):
      utc = pytz.utc
      fmt = '%a %d-%b-%Y'
      time_fmt = '%H:%M:%S'
      utc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_date))
      utc_time = utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time))
      hki_tz = timezone('Europe/Helsinki') # refer documentation for the TZ adjustments
      hki_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(hki_tz)
      return hki_dt.strftime(fmt), utc_time.strftime(time_fmt)
```

and to get the values:

```
unixDate = 1706392800
unixTime = 79800
hkiDate, hkiTime = convert_date_time(unixDate,unixTime)
print(f"Today's date and time is: {hkiDate}, {hkiTime}")
```

the output looks like this:

```
Today's date and time is: Sun 28-Jan-2024, 22:10:00
```