# How do I compare DateTime objects to UNIX timestamps when filtering results in django?

Tags: django, unix, datetime, timestamp, fullcalendar

I am using the FullCalendar plugin for JQuery.

This plugin passes a unix timestamp to a url (both start and end times), which is then used to query the event objects in the database and pull out events which fall within the range of start-end.

However, I keep getting a validation error because the times in my database are stored as datetimes and the value I am comparing them to is a UNIX timestamp.

How can I compare these two dates when running a query?

```
def fetch_events(request):
    start = request.GET.get('start')
    end = request.GET.get('end')
    e = Event.objects.filter(start__gte=start, end__lte=end).values('id','title','start','end')
    data = simplejson.dumps(list(e), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: this is a duplicate question, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making a `datetime` object from a timestamp by using the `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` function. Here's a quick demonstration:

```
In [7]: import datetime

In [8]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(2344353453)
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2044, 4, 15, 19, 17, 33)
```

Comment: Absolutely excellent! Had to also convert the get string number to an integer: `start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(start))`