# How to convert timestamp string to datetime object?

Tags: python, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

I have a timestamp:

```
t = 1322745926.123
```

How to convert timestamp to datetime object ?

```
datetime.strptime(t,date_format)
```

What should `date_format` be in the above function call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

datetime.strptime() is not the right function for your problem. It convertes a string like "30 Nov 00" to a struct_time object.

You propably want

```
from datetime import datetime
t = 1322745926.123
datetime.fromtimestamp(t).isoformat()
```

The result from this code is

```
'2011-12-01T14:25:26.123000'
```

if your timecode is a string you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
t = "1322745926.123"
datetime.fromtimestamp(float(t)).isoformat()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1322745926.123)
```

returns `datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 13, 25, 26, 123000)` which is in the UTC timezone. With:

```
a = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1322745926.123))
```

you get a timezone-aware datetime object which can be then converted to any timezone you need:

```
a == datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 13, 25, 26, 123000, tzinfo=<UTC>)

a.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))

# datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 14, 25, 26, 123000, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

Comment: +1, PyTZ is a nice library, but it should be noted that is not part of the standard python installation.

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
```