# How to convert string timestamp to datetime object in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas column with timestamp strings in the format '00:00:00.000' (hours, minutes, seconds, micro seconds). I would like to convert them to `datetime` objects to work on the seconds.

I have seen many similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400687/how-to-convert-timestamp-string-to-datetime-object) for example. I am guessing that I should use `strptime` but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If convert values to datetimes in pandas, also there is added some default `date` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

If need avoid it convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'])
```

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh - Ya, I know, explained more.