# how do i convert unix timestamp in integer to human readable format in django template?

Tags: django, templates, date, timestamp

I store the date as integer field in my database and called it timestamp. When I display it in template, I tried to use `{{ timestamp | date:"D d M Y" }}`, however, this does not output anything for me.

Did I do anything wrong?

Edit:
Sorry for the typo, I did put date: instead of date= in my code. However, since the timestamp was integer field, should I convert it to datetime before doing this? Can I do it in the template itself? Since this line of code is in the middle of iterating an array of object in the template.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a custom templatetag filter. I made this one for you: just make sure you have a `templatetags` folder in the *app directory* and then create an empty file `__init__.py` in the directory. Also save the code below in the templatetag directory as `timestamp_to_time.py`.
Also make sure that the app containing this templatetag directory is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings variable.

```
from django import template    
register = template.Library()    

@register.filter('timestamp_to_time')
def convert_timestamp_to_time(timestamp):
    import time
    return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
```

In your template you can then use the filter as follow:

```
{{ value|timestamp_to_time|date:"jS N, Y" }}
```

*{# replace **value** with the timestamp value and then **format** the time as you want #}*

Be sure to have loaded the templatetag filter in the template with

```
{% load timestamp_to_time %}
```

before trying to use the filter

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ timestamp|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

"=" != ":" ;)

### EDIT:

If you have access to the view I would suggest sending the date to the template as a datetime object, not an integer.

> From documentation: {{ value|date:"D d M Y" }} If value is a datetime object
>   (e.g., the result of datetime.datetime.now()), the output will be the
>   string 'Wed 09 Jan 2008'.

Here's a link to date function documentation: [Django|Built-in-template-tags-and-filters|Date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date)

Have you also tried printing out just the integer to see if there actually is the correct value in it?

Comment: Is it too short of an answer? :)

Comment: it is subjective, but someone can consider a bad netiquette. I did not voted down your answer.

Comment: oops. actually it was date:"D d M Y", {{ timestamp|date:"D d M Y" }}.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately not working for timestamps. Might have to go filter route.

Answer (score 1):

To work with Django's builtin date filter you should use a [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) or [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield). 
Note that you can easily [convert a timestamp to python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3682748/630877), which is the format used by the DateField.

Also check the docs for the [correct syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date):

```
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

Comment: The raw timestamp is an integer field. For the above example, if i just output the timestamp, it prints "1327871672".

Comment: Then you should either convert the timestamp field to a datetime field so you can use the builtin date filter or you should write your own filter/tag that formats unix timestamps.