# converting long format time into proper time in django templtes list?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a time value for every entry coming in long time format from API.So i want to convert it into human readable form.

my API values are:-

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 33613,
      "virtualNewsId": 30513,
      "newsCommentText": "@39586!~~!Abhay_raj_singh_chauhan!~~!Abhay%20Raj%20%20!>>! @39586!~~!Abhay_raj_singh_chauhan!~~!Abhay%20Raj%20%20!>>!",
      "user": {
        "id": 39561,
        "name": "chatuser",
        "username": "chatuser",
        "email": "chatuser@mail.com",
        "profileImage": "",
        "profileImageThumbnail": "",
        "isfollow": false
      },
      "image": null,
      "createdAt": 1493978312000
    }
```

now how can i convert createdAt human readable forn in django template.I have many values like this and uaing forloop to display on tables.So how can i achieve this.

Comment: Is this working `{{ createdAt |date:"D d M Y" }}` ?

Comment: not working @L_S i tried this

Comment: @AbiWaqas Is this you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14708395/7724457

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in django by writing a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) that parses your timestamp into a human readable format.

```
{% parsetimestamp createdAt %}
```

---

```
import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='parsetimestamp')
def parser(value):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value/1000)
```

Or do it trivially in Javascript:

```
<span>
   <script>document.write(Date({{ createdAt }}))</script>
</span>
```

Comment: A filter is probably better since the default `date` one can be chained together with it.