# Converting a floating point number (seconds) to a string (date)

Tags: datetime, time, python-2.7

I am attempting to convert a floating point number, in this case seconds, into a YYMMDDHHMM format. I have tried numerous ways only to either get an error dealing with the fact that I haven't properly converted the float OR that when I have completed the conversion it is not in UTC/GMT time. This occured when I tried to use the function "ctime". When I inputted 0 for s when using ctime it printed a time 6 hours before Jan 1st, 1970.

Here's what I have that's missing the conversion:

```
import time

s = 1226368439.04

#conversion of some sort here

print time.strftime(s)
```

Any assistance would be wonderful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

import time

t = 1226368439.04

time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.localtime(t))

20081111072359

time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.gmtime(t))

'20081111015359'