# Python: Number of seconds since midnight 1970.01.01 GMT to arbitrary time GMT?

Tags: python

Having a difficult time with this, trying all these different date functions but no clue how to do it with any certainty.

Comment: Like in this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python

Comment: Maybe. specifically, everything needs to be in GMT timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `calendar.timegm` to get seconds since epoch. A time tuple is the required parameter and `time.strptime` can be used to generate that tuple.

Here is a quick example:

```
import calendar
import time

# Time in GMT
x = 'Sat Jul 14 22:05:54 2012'
y = time.strptime(x)
z = calendar.timegm(y)
print z # 1342303554 - the number of seconds since epoch
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is by definition in GMT (or rather [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) format. You can use pythons [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module and create a datetime object with timezone "None" by using the [utcfromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) constructor:

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(300)
1970-01-01 00:05:00
```

If you use the [fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) constructor, you will get a datetime object *adjusted* for the timezone of your environment (in my case UTC+1):

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(300)
1970-01-01 01:05:00
```