# Convert time to unix time

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

When I do `time.time()` I get something like: `1342648659.223746`. How can I convert it to unix time that looks like this: `2012-07-18T21:42:00Z`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's standard [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module is quite handy for all kinds of date/time manipulation.

For your particular problem, the [`isoformat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) method is handy. For example, if you already have a time in seconds since the Epoch (such as your `1342648659.223746`):

```
>> from datetime import datetime
>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1342648659.223746).isoformat()
== '2012-07-18T23:57:39.223746'
```

And if you just want the current (UTC) time, ISO formatted:

```
>> datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
== '2012-07-19T00:06:45.724468'
```

If you absolutely require the timezone information in your output (i.e. the `Z` for UTC in your example), you'll either have to append it manually, or fall back to using `strftime`:

```
>> datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
== '2012-07-18T22:11:05Z'
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `datetime` module as below:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(27654727.23)
>>> print d
1970-11-16 22:52:07.230000
```

You could pass the timestamp to the `fromtimestamp()` function.