# Converting Timestamp to Javascript Date object in python

Tags: javascript, python, timestamp

My unix timestamp is something like this `1386181800`.

I have to convert it into Javascript readable Date format which looks like this ,and all this iam trying to come up in python.

```
new Date('2010','0','3','10','10')
```

Comment: And have you tried anything yourself yet? Why is this tagged with Python?

Comment: Oh yeah im trying to do this in python

Comment: What are you trying to do in Python, produce a string that JavaScript can interpret?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

Comment: No i have to read a timestamp in python,and convert in into a javascript readable date format ,so that my client site can read those dates and come up with some graphs.

Comment: Take a look at [other ways to instantiate a `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) in Javascript, something might pop up.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript