# python equivallent command for date unix command

Tags: python, unix

I have unix command

`echo 1378312014 | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date -d "@{}" "+%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M"`

equivalent output is `04-09-2013-17-26`

Is there any python in build library that can convert `1378312014`  to `04-09-2013-17-26`

I am completely new to python, but I don't want to use os.popen or subprocess because they are running unix commands. I want to know if I can do it in python datetime library.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) to convert a UNIX timestamp to a `datetime` object:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1378312014)
print dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M')
```

The `datetime.datetime.strftime()` formats the object as a string with a desired format.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1378312014)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 4, 17, 26, 54)
>>> print dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M')
04-09-2013-17-26
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the time module too:

```
 import time
 time.strftime("%d-%m:%Y-%H-%M", time.localtime(1378312014))
```