# Python - Convert timestamp including timezone (+0200) to humanly readable

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I can't for the life of me figure out how to convert a timestamp on the form `1433140740000+0200` to a `datetime` object or to any humanly readable representation. Also, what format is this specifically? I'm assuming the `+0200` represents a timezone.

I can only seem to find questions regarding timestamps without timezones, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682808/1531637), where `int("1433140740000+0200")` would give me an error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** As mentioned in a comment, further examination of the API from which I am getting these values reveals other timestamps with different values for what I thought to represent timezones. E.g: `315529200000+0100`. The entire line of data looks like this: `"ArrivalTime": "/Date(1433051640000+0200)/"`, and the full response can be found [here](http://reis.trafikanten.no/reisrest/Travel/GetTravelsAdvanced/?time=010620151242&fromstops=3010045:1,3010031:15&tostops=3010013,3010011:1&changeMargin=2&changePunish=8&walkingFactor=100&isAfter=True&proposals=5&transporttypes=Bus,Train,Tram,Metro).

**Second edit:** As far as I can tell, the timestamps are unix timestamps, but they're given in milliseconds (hence the trailing zeros), and the `+0200` indicates timezone UTC+02:00. So for now, I'll just trim out the extra zeros and the timezone, and convert as shown in the linked question, before adding the timezone manually afterwards. The timestamps with +0100 remain a mystery to me, but I've found they're always the same date, 1/1/1980 12:00am. They also have a different identifier: `ActualTime`, as opposed to `ArrivalTime` on the others. Anyway, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: It's time offsets then... if you take a flight an hour west that takes exactly an hour, then you arrive at the same time you left. However, it'd be -0100 from your origin.

Comment: The API is for the local public transportation, so I doubt it's offset, really. In addition, all the timestamps with +0100 seems to represent midnight 1/1/1980 for some reason, while the ones with +0200 make sense.

Comment: ahhh.... got to love sane data - sounds like you're going to have fun with that :)

Comment: Haha indeed, they could at the very least mention what it's supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string split to remove the timezone

```
import datetime
intstring = int( ('1433140740000+0200').split('+')[0])

print(
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(intstring/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

I had to change it to this to make it work

intstring /1000

Comment: how did he get these 0000 in timestamp?

Comment: He will need to figure out what the timestamp really means.

Comment: @themaze note - this won't work with negative timestamp offsets (ie... you might also need to throw in a split on `-` as well)

Comment: This may do the trick
    intstring = '1433140740000+0200'
    intstring = int(re.split(r'(\d+)', intstring)[1])

Comment: @themaze Just slice and take off the last five `[:-5]` chars instead

Comment: Hi guys, I got the timestamps from an API, but it's quite poorly documented, so return values are not explained. Exploring the API, I find other timestamps, this time with +0100, suggesting these are, in fact, not timezones. The full value is this: ArrivalTime": "/Date(1433140740000+0200)/. Thanks for replies!