# Converting a unixtime to human readable date format

Tags: python, django, datetime, strftime

Hi I have a unixtime stamp (type= long). So when I tried to convert in to date format by this following method,

`def render_validation_time(self, value):
        x = value.filter(field_name='pdbstatus').latest('id')
        validated_time = int(x.date_modified)
        return validated_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

But it returned an error `'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'`
How can I solve this?

Comment: You probably want [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3682808/103081) to the above link.

Comment: Thanks Bro. It solved my problem :)