# Convert a particular timestamp with Python 2.7.x

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp like:

`2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z`

How do I convert this so that I can easily get the month like "January"? And in general convert it to a nice format like:

`January 1st, 2014`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: So here's a similar question. I think it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module. `datetime.datetime` expects a time string and its formatting and returns a `datetime.datetime` object, on which you can call `strftime()` to [format it according to your needs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
>>> my_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
01.01.2014
>>> date.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y')
'05:00:00 01.01.2014'
```

There is also a [python-dateutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module, [which can do the same.](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html)

Comment: It doesn't produce `January 1st, 2014`. `.strftime('%B %-d, %Y')` produces `'January 1, 2015'` (note: `1`, not `1st`).

Answer (score 1):

The strftime() method in datetime modulecan achieve this. It expects a string pattern explaining how you want to format your date.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
print today.strftime('It is %d %b %Y')
```

The above code prints something like "It is 12 Nov 2015"

You can find more format codes at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior