# UTS to DateTime in Python from Last.fm API

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, last.fm

The last.fm API using user.getRecentTracks method's response supplies a date in the following format:

```
"date": {
    "#text": "11 Dec 2015, 01:41", 
    "uts": "1449798068"
},
```

What is this "uts" field and how do I convert it into datetime string for a MySql database in python? Would your suggested answer be more efficient than using datetime.datetime.strptime() method to convert the text string given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uts` looks like a timestamp. The abbreviation probably stands for UTC timestamp or Unix Timestamp. I'm not sure which, but, it simple to convert it to a `datetime` object

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1449798068)
>>> print(dt)
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 10, 20, 41, 8)
```

It seems the `#text` key has the time in a local timezone, which is five hours ahead.

Comment: @JasonMeloHall: do you see that the time in the answer differs from "#text" value? Note: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` returns a correct value here. Read [my comment to the corresponding answer on the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python#comment30046351_3682808)

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian. That was my mistake. Since the question is duplicate, I wont amend my answer. Jason, please refer to the linked question & maybe consider deleting this thread.