# getting the specific weekday number, specific hour, specific minute, and specific second from unix timestmap in python

Tags: python, date, unix-timestamp

How can I get the specific day number, specific hour, specific minute, and specific second from unix timestmap in python?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's can be done pretty easy using python [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp)

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1456741175
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(dt.day)
# Week day number
print(dt.weekday())
print(dt.minute)
print(dt.second)
```

Use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) module if you work with timezone aware timestamps

Comment: I want the week day number

Comment: Use dt.weekday(). All attributes described here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a timestamp that is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = time.time()
utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)    # UTC time
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)           # local time

>>> print(utc_dt)
2016-02-29 10:27:34.753077
>>> print(dt)
2016-02-29 21:27:34.753077
>>> print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0))
1970-01-01 00:00:00
>>> print(datetime.fromtimestamp(0))
1970-01-01 10:00:00
```

You can extract the individual fields using the attributes of the `datetime` object using `dt.day`, `dt.hour`, `dt.minute`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import datetime

time_stamp = 1456741030
date_time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time_stamp)
print(date_time.year)    # 2016
print(date_time.month)   # 2
print(date_time.day)     # 29
print(date_time.hour)    # 10
print(date_time.minute)  # 17
print(date_time.second)  # 10
```