# CSV file's created_at date?

Tags: csv

I am applying for a job and the application requires basic programming knowledge and gives you a question. I have to use this [CSV file (Google doc)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFgQ6JNLvc-QXdXSWdwS2RKZWc/view) and find the rows where the user was created between June 22nd, 2014 and July 22nd, 2014 then make them ascending order.

Here's a small extract from the data:

```
id  created_at  first_name  last_name   …
1   1309380645  Stephanie   Franklin    …
2   1237178109  Michelle    Fowler      …
3   1303585711  Betty       Barnes      …
```

I could easily write the program in Ruby or Python, but my only issue is I can't understand the `created_at` date. I'm pretty sure the first two numbers are the year but I've never seen a date formatted this way. How should I interpret that `created_at` column?

Comment: Looks like it might be 'seconds since the epoch', or 1970-01-01 00:00:00 *00:00.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Incidentally, in the US/Pacific time zone, `1309380645 = Wed Jun 29 13:50:45 2011`,
`1237178109 = Sun Mar 15 21:35:09 2009`,
`1303585711 = Sat Apr 23 12:08:31 2011`, and also
`1403424000 = 2014-06-22 00:00:00`, 
`1406102399 = 2014-07-22 23:59:59`.  None of the sample data rows in the question is within the time frame.  Presumably, other rows in the Google Doc are within the time frame.

Answer (score 1):

That date format is called a UNIX Timestamp and as Jonathan Leffler has said, its the amount of seconds from the 1st Jan 1970.

You can run one of those numbers through a converter (http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) and it will translate the integer into a formatted date (1309380645 = 'Wed, 29 Jun 2011 20:50:45 GMT').

EDIT: Take a look at this thread about converting the UNIX timestamp into a formatted string [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python).