# How to load csv file to matrix python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, matrix

I have a .CSV file named TEMP2.csv which contains the following:

`1376460059,4,33.29,33.23,33.23,33.29,33.23,33.29,33.29,33.29,33.33,33.29,33.33,33.29,33.33,33.33,33.37,33.33,33.33,33.33,33.33,33.37,33.37,33.37,33.37`

This is how I am reading the file:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('TEMP2.csv',delimiter=',', skip_header=2)
```

After skipping the fisrt two number I need to add the next 4 numbers to a first row in a matrix. The next 4 to the second row in the same matrix and so on.

However that is just not working, I am really new to python been trying for some days and still I do not get the results. I will apreciate your help so much. Thanks.

Comment: What is the `dtype` and `shape` of `data`?

Comment: This may solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: data type "float" not really sure abobut the shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).And add zero to the end of array if it can't reshape.

```
COLUMN_NUM = 4
data = np.genfromtxt('a.csv', delimiter=',')[2:]

if data.shape[0] % 4 == 0:
    print data.reshape((-1, 4))
else:
    data = np.pad(data, (0, COLUMN_NUM - len(data) % COLUMN_NUM), 'constant')
    print data.reshape((-1, COLUMN_NUM))
```

**The new shape should be compatible with the original shape.** So it reshape successfully,you will get this result:

```
[[ 33.29  33.23  33.23  33.29]
 [ 33.23  33.29  33.29  33.29]
 [ 33.33  33.29  33.33  33.29]
 [ 33.33  33.33  33.37  33.33]
 [ 33.33  33.33  33.33  33.37]
 [ 33.37  33.37  33.37  33.11]]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sure help me a lot @McGrady. Could you now please help me here: That first number it's a Unix Timestamp. The second its the frecuency the rest number where generated. What would be the best way to know the time they were generated?

Comment: @CristianJEstrada Have a look at [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

Comment: I will, also I tried to getting the mean out of the first row but instead it will give me the mean out of everthing.

Comment: @CristianJEstrada You'd better ask another question,

Comment: I was able to do it:

     for x in range(0, len(data)):
         xtime = ((x*1.)/COLUMN_NUM) + 1376460059
         xtime = np.array(xtime)  
         print xtime

Do you know how to append my results to the matrix you have showed me before?