# Replacing a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code which is pulling data into a pandas dataframe.

```
df = df[["date","high","low","open","close"]]
```

The data looks like this:

```
       date         high          low        open       close
0  1499140800  2615.390000  2600.000000  2610.58000  2603.00000
1  1499155200  2618.785462  2582.002100  2615.00000  2607.00000
2  1499169600  2617.674406  2550.314214  2607.00000  2554.55010
3  1499184000  2572.962113  2519.967440  2554.55010  2519.96744
4  1499198400  2595.654622  2516.000000  2519.96744  2580.00000
```

I am wanting to convert the unix timestamp column with an actual datetime. Earlier in my code am having to import

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and it seems to be giving me an error when I try to use datetime.datetime to convert. I can't just use `import datetime`because this gives me an error on my previous import which I need. So my question is twofold. How can I convert the timestamp into a datetime (possibly without using the datetime module?) and how can I overwrite the date column with the new date time before I save into a file?I have tried several approaches but none seem to be giving me any luck..

Comment: Have you tried using pandas solution? `pd.to_datetime(arg)`

Comment: That's a great little solution and I am all for using one liners. Really nice thank you. However this seems to give me the output "1970-01-01 00:00:01.499155200"? which still has the stamp somehow attached? Also you don't answer how I can now replace my date column and inject it into the dataframe before I save it down!

Comment: I recommend you take another look at @MaxU's answer.  Its vectorized and at least deserves your up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me after I copied your example data to a file `in.csv`

An explanation follows the code example.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_csv('in.csv')

>>> df
     date         high          low        open       close
0  1499140800  2615.390000  2600.000000  2610.58000  2603.00000
1  1499155200  2618.785462  2582.002100  2615.00000  2607.00000
2  1499169600  2617.674406  2550.314214  2607.00000  2554.55010
3  1499184000  2572.962113  2519.967440  2554.55010  2519.96744
4  1499198400  2595.654622  2516.000000  2519.96744  2580.00000

>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> converted = df['date'].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)

>>> df['date'] = converted

>>> df
              date         high          low        open       close
0 2017-07-03 22:00:00  2615.390000  2600.000000  2610.58000  2603.00000
1 2017-07-04 02:00:00  2618.785462  2582.002100  2615.00000  2607.00000
2 2017-07-04 06:00:00  2617.674406  2550.314214  2607.00000  2554.55010
3 2017-07-04 10:00:00  2572.962113  2519.967440  2554.55010  2519.96744
4 2017-07-04 14:00:00  2595.654622  2516.000000  2519.96744  2580.00000
```

#### Converting a Unix Timestamp to Datetime

You ran

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and expected to use `datetime.datetime` later as a function, but you actually imported the `datetime` class from the `datetime` module (which is why changing the import to just `datetime` didn't help). See this question for more: [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

So you just need to import the datetime class and use its `fromtimestamp` function

#### Updating a Column in a DataFrame

For this, a common approach is to `apply` a function (in this case, `fromtimestamp`) to the column (a Pandas `Series`) and then over-write the old column in the DataFrame.

I am not aware of a way to modify the column in place, but would be happy to hear a way if I missed it in the Pandas docs.

Comment: Two lines..absolutely brilliant! Thank you so much! Gotta love python and the great community it has!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
         date         high          low        open       close
0  1499140800  2615.390000  2600.000000  2610.58000  2603.00000
1  1499155200  2618.785462  2582.002100  2615.00000  2607.00000
2  1499169600  2617.674406  2550.314214  2607.00000  2554.55010
3  1499184000  2572.962113  2519.967440  2554.55010  2519.96744
4  1499198400  2595.654622  2516.000000  2519.96744  2580.00000

In [3]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
                 date         high          low        open       close
0 2017-07-04 04:00:00  2615.390000  2600.000000  2610.58000  2603.00000
1 2017-07-04 08:00:00  2618.785462  2582.002100  2615.00000  2607.00000
2 2017-07-04 12:00:00  2617.674406  2550.314214  2607.00000  2554.55010
3 2017-07-04 16:00:00  2572.962113  2519.967440  2554.55010  2519.96744
4 2017-07-04 20:00:00  2595.654622  2516.000000  2519.96744  2580.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vinicius Aguiar said in the comment, you can also use `pd.to_datetime()`.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```