# Convert time stamp to combined date and time in UTC in Python

Tags: python-2.7, date, time, utc

I pulled some data from an API in JSON format. The data contains a Unix time stamp and information about the timezone. My question is how do I add the time zone info (in bold) at the end of the datetime object?

Combined date and time in UTC(according to ISO 8601): 2017-07-29T12:48:20+**00:00**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and import `python-dateutil`. Make sure to convert the time stamp into datetime (divide stamp with 1e3 if it is longer than 10 characters) and then use the dateutil package to add the time zone info at the end with `tzoffset` like so:

```
time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1e3).replace(tzinfo=tzoffset(None, timezone))
```

Comment: It works.. thank you. What is up with the '1e3'? What does it do once it divides the var?

Comment: `1e3` is 10^3. `fromtimestamp` expects timestamp in second so when you divide var by 1e3 you convert millisecond to second. (BTW - if it answered your query then why don't accept it as the right answer ;) )

Comment: It partially did... I'm reading the docs on the datetime module, trying to figure out how to do this. Check out my edit.

Comment: try `time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(var/1e3).replace(tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -480)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z')`

Comment: I tried it and got a syntax  error for encoding... I don't know what 'tzoffset' is. I found 'utcoffset' on the docs page. Maybe you meant that?
Either way after changing this returned the same result.

I then found this: 
" If you merely want to attach a time zone object tz to a datetime dt without adjustment of date and time data, use dt.replace(tzinfo=tz) "
Which returned:
" TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'int' "

Comment: add `from dateutil.tz import tzoffset`

Comment: That did it. I'll re-edit my OP to structure this thread so it looks readable.

Comment: Glad that it helped :)