# Datetime fromtimestamp return wrong year

Tags: python

I am trying to convert time stamp to human date. i am doing that in order to get the local time of a message and insert it into our database as human date.

currently if i use the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
     reference_date1 = datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    delta_since_reference = timedelta(seconds=530023775)
    print str(reference_date1 + delta_since_reference)
```

i get:

```
2017-10-18 12:49:35
```

which there the date is correct but the hour is wrong.
and if i use:

```
print datetime.fromtimestamp(530023775)
```

i get:

```
1986-10-18 14:49:35
```

which here the hour is correct but the year is wrong.
there is a way to merge between the 2 results? 
or there is a better approach to convert time stamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to convert time stamp to "human" date, try to do like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

your_time_stamp = int("1284101485")
human_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(your_time_stamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This solution has been taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python) (another stackoverflow post).

Comment: printing 1986-10-18 14:49:35 instead 2017-10-18 14:49:35

Comment: Your script prints `1986-10-18 14:49:35` because your time stamp 530023775 represents this date. I guess you want to get the current date, so try to do this: `datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to add in `reference_date1` when calculating the the datetime using `fromtimestamp()`.

Here is the updated code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
reference_date1 = datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
delta_since_reference = timedelta(seconds=530023775)
print(str(reference_date1 + delta_since_reference))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(530023775 + float(datetime.strptime(str(reference_date1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%s'))))
```

Which prints

```
2017-10-18 12:49:35
2017-10-18 12:49:35
```

Comment: the second print is print a wrong time, the correct time should be 14:49:35

Comment: i get Traceback "'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'" for print(datetime.fromtimestamp(530023775 + reference_date1.timestamp()))

Comment: Are you sure that you're supposed to get 14 as the hour? `(530023775/(60*60))%24 = 12.83` This indicates that the remaining hours after taking off a number of days is 12.83. So, it would make sense that the hours is 12 since the time on your reference date is 00:00. As for the Traceback error, it turns out that datetime.datetime.timestamp is only available in Python 3. I will update my answer to be compatible with Python 2.

Comment: currently i see in https://www.epochconverter.com/ that in GMT time is 12 but in local time is 14. it is bit confusing me because the diffrent between my time to the local time should be 1 hour. this is the local time there, https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/zimbabwe/harare and now on my clock is 10:37

Comment: You may need to do some timezone conversion after converting the seconds since reference date to a datetime

Comment: yes probably i will have to do that. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your first try you use 1.1.2001 as your reference date:

```
reference_date1 = datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Where as according to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), `datetime.fromtimestamp`:

> Return the local date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time(). [..] Note that on **non-POSIX systems that include leap seconds in their notion of a timestamp, leap seconds are ignored by fromtimestamp()**

*Emphasis mine*

And a POSIX timestamp is:

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or epoch time)[citation needed] is a system for describing a point in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970

So:

- The dates are different because of the different reference date. Simply decide what standard you want to adhere to
- The hours on my PC are the same (I use a POSIX-compliant macOS), but they might differ on your PC if you use a non-POSIX system

---

**Solutions:**

- If you only need to print the date

  `datetime.now()`
- If you need the date both as timestamp and printable

  `datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())`