# Compare and convert two datetime objects in JSON to Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime

I am using Python's requests module to fetch data from a website. In the JSON response object, I have a key `created at` and its value is `1520369492984`.I am totally lost as to how to convert this to a Datetime object in Python. `pd.to_datetime` failed. Any pointers on this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: @pault: I tried but that raised a `ValueError` saying `year is out of range`.

Comment: You should consult the documentation for the API to see what format the value is in. That said, it *appears* to be a regular UNIX timestamp with milliseconds appended (i.e., an integer-encode version of `1520369492.984`).

Comment: Try `datetime.fromtimestamp(1520369492984/1000)`

Comment: @chepner : Great thanks! There is no proper documentation for this part but the conversion produced the exact date! Thank you!

Comment: Arguably, such a value shouldn't be used at all, preferring instead something defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're getting is called `epoch` Date Time.

```
import time
time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.localtime(1520369492984/1000))
```

Or using the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1520369492984/1000).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

**Background Story:**

The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). Literally speaking the epoch is Unix time 0 (midnight 1/1/1970), but 'epoch' is often used as a synonym for 'Unix time'.

> You can find online converters for the same. My personal recommendation: [epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

The above not only converts the timestamp but also, gives you code snippets for different languages.

Comment: Great! This format is what I was looking for! Thanks for the notes as well!

Comment: glad I could help.

Comment: :) Same pinch! I am from the same country as you!! And thank you again!!

Comment: Your bio obviously!

Comment: Lol I figured that too