# How to convert unix timestamp to date-time in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have unix timestamps that starts from `1970-01-01` in `csv` file as column. I want their corresponding date-time but when I am using  `pd.to_datetime()` I am getting date something like this: `1970-01-16 20:55:29.694`.

Comment: `datetime.datetime` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting.?

Answer (score 0):

From your affirmation, I will assume that you want to extract something specific (let's keep it in the same format) from the output of `pd.to_datetime()` or use another pandas function.

If this is the case, I would proceed as follows :

```
    import pandas as pd
    t = '2018-07-25' # your excel date
    t_ex = pd.Timestamp(t) 
    # t_ex == 2018-07-25 00:00:00
    t_ex_format = m = str(t_ex.year)+'-'+str(t_ex.month)+'-'+str(t_ex.day) 
    # t_ex_format = 2018-07-25
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I didnt asked my question properly. I have a column of timestamp which has unix timestamps( eg. 1364099483). I want to convert this to its corresponding date-time which should is 24 March 2013 04:31:23. But the result which I am getting is 1/16/1970 18:54. Code which I am using for this is: 
dataset['DATE']=(pd.to_datetime(dataset['timestamp'],unit='ms'))

Comment: Thanks. It was done, I was not passing the origin parameter.