# Converting a given unix time stamp to readable format

Tags: python, time

I'm using an API. The API returns JSON data with a timestamp. The response looks like this:

`{'time_gmt': 1213329060, 'day_ind': 'N' ...}`

I've familiarity with Python's DateTime objects, but I'm not able to comprehend this time format. Is there any way we can convert it into a more readable format?

Comment: Unix timestamp? Try in https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: What you call `GMT time format` is the readable format. That looks like a Unix timestamp.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh I didn't know about Unix timestamp. I'm sorry, would update the title.

Comment: `GMT` refers to a specific timezone. `time_gmt` means that the time is in that timezone, not that it has a specific format. There's no specific JSON date format but the defacto standard is the ISO8601 format, ie `2019-01-01T17:04+02:00`. You should probably change the API or contact the author to use the standard version if possible

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you so much, I've found the solution on SO, should I  close the question?

Comment: Turning unix timestamps into readable strings can be done like this: `import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1213329060))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int("1213329060")
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else said before me, that is indeed a UNIX timestamp. Very common.

How to convert that into a readable format has been asked before a few times. Here is a nice example:
[converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Which is the same example that everyone else here posted before me :)

What is missing, is that this website here explains what the flags are that are used to convert the UNIX timestamp:
http://strftime.org/

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I've marked the question as a duplicate.