# Python convert from ordinal time with milliseconds

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have a couple of timestamps in ordinal time such as for example 737778.582024. I want to convert it to something understandable, preferrably a datetime object. The number probably contains information down to as small as milliseconds.

In MATLAB there is the function `datetime()` which will give my expected result:

```matlab
>> t = datetime(737778.582024,'ConvertFrom','datenum')

t = 

  datetime

   19-Dec-2019 13:58:06
```

In Python I could only find the function `datetime.fromordinal()` which only takes integers as input and thus can only convert to a date.

```py
from datetime import  datetime
datetime.fromordinal(737778.582024)
```

> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Is there a python function similar to the MATLAB one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: Sadly not. Dont confuse ordinal time with, unix time