# How to convert getmtime() to datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm working with data whose time format is in datetime and looks like the following `'modified': '2016-08-24T12:52:39.780790+00:00'`. I'm looking to retrieve the modification time of a file on my O.S which is returned in this format `1606414504.705609` and convert it to match the format I've shown above. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: from the datetime module, import datetime and timezone, then `datetime.fromtimestamp(1606414504.705609, tz=timezone.utc).isoformat()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: btw. the *format* is specified [here: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: @MrFuppes Hi, yes this does answer my question! Thank you! Would you like to put your answer down as the main answer so I can select it as the solution? Your first comment answered my question, not the second

Comment: I'm glad if I could help you, no need for an extra answer here. I've added a more [concise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418) to the linked question (comment #2).