# unix timestamp's output using datetime.utcfromtimestamp() differs from its correct value

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I have followed [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date) in order to convert unix timestamp string into a readable date.

> ```
> from datetime import datetime ts = int("1284101485")
> print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
> ```

---

As input when I provider `1607111882000`; it prints `2020-12-04 19:58:02`. But on the following site (https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), the output is as follows:

```py
1607111882000
Is equivalent to:

05/06/52897 @ 11:13pm (UTC)
52897-05-06T23:13:20+00:00 in ISO 8601

Mon, 06 May 52897 23:13:20 +0000 in RFC 822, 1036, 1123, 2822

Monday, 06-May-97 23:13:20 UTC in RFC 2822

52897-05-06T23:13:20+00:00 in RFC 3339
```

---

Why is there this difference and which one is correct? What should I do to obtain the same result as in the unixtimestamp.com site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website is probably using `time.ctime` or an equivalent function:

```
>>> time.ctime(time.mktime(time.gmtime(1607111882000)))
'Mon May  6 23:13:20 52897'
```

As to whether or not it's correct to use that is debatable. The date might not be 100% accurate.

For your number, I think you put milliseconds instead of seconds as on my machine it gives an error (`ValueError: year is out of range`), but dividing by 1000 gives the correct date for both functions:

```
>>> ts = 1607111882
>>> print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
2020-12-04 19:58:02
>>> time.ctime(time.mktime(time.gmtime(ts)))
'Fri Dec  4 19:58:02 2020'
>>>
```

Comment: Can the result converted into different time-zone such as for `Istanbul`?

Comment: @alper Yes. A simple trick would just be to add the offset in seconds to the timestamp. For a better solution, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone); something like `datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, timezone(timedelta(hours=timezone_offset)))` could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You right. And unixtimestamp (UT) wrong. I think UT mistake between second and milliseconds.

Let access https://unixtime.org/ , this website Supports Unix timestamps in seconds, milliseconds, microseconds and nanoseconds.

Example: 1607111882000
Result:
Format  Milliseconds (1/1,000 second)
GMT Fri Dec 04 2020 19:58:02 GMT+0000
Relative    3 months ago