# How to easily create a datetime object from time with unit since epoch?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, python-3.7

let's say I got a timestamp since epoch in microseconds `1611590898133828` how could I convert this easily into a datetime object considering the unit `microseconds`.

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp_micro = 1611590898133828
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_micro / 1e6)
```

I would like to be able to do easy conversions since sometimes I have microseconds, sometimes seconds, sometimes nanoseconds to convert.

```
timestamp_micro = 1611590898133828
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_micro, unit="us")
```

Is this somehow possible? For me using python's datetime package is just one pain. Maybe you can also recommend another package in which timestamp handling is easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) provides the option to set the [unit as a keyword](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases):

```
import pandas as pd

t, UNIT = 1611590898133828, 'us'

dt = pd.to_datetime(t, unit=UNIT)

print(dt, repr(dt))
# 2021-01-25 16:08:18.133828 Timestamp('2021-01-25 16:08:18.133828')
```

You can now work with pandas' timestamps or convert to a regular Python datetime object like

```
dt.to_pydatetime()
# datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 25, 16, 8, 18, 133828)
```

Please also note that if you use `fromtimestamp` without setting a time zone, you'll get naive datetime, which will be treated as *local time* by Python (UTC offset might not be 0). See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418).

Answer (score 0):

You can create new javascript date objects by simply calling `const dt = new Date(timestamp)`. The `timestamp` value here is an epoch up to milliseconds precision. JavaScript does have native support for higher precision.

If you constantly need to work with dates, I would recommend you to use a package such as momentJS, since native JS is quite a pain to handle dates/times.