# How to convert unix epoch time to datetime with timezone in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, datetime, timezone

I have many csv files containing Unix epoch time which needs to be converted to human readable date/time. The following Python code does the job but it is very slow.

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch'], unit='s')
df['dt'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['dt'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam'), axis=1)
```

Actually, the second line is the bottleneck (~30 seconds for 1 million rows). So even with the aid of multiprocessing, it is not scalable as I have more than a billion records totally. How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The question pertains to `pandas`, the pure python version is [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3682748/7758804)
- [`pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) & [`pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) are both vectorized functions, which don't require using `.apply()`.

  - The vectorized implementation is **8159 times faster** than `.apply()`.
  - The `.dt` accessor must be used.
- It may be better to use `pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], unit='s', utc=True)` and remove `.dt.tz_localize('UTC')`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe with 1M rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'DT': [1349720105, 1349806505, 1349892905, 1349979305, 1350065705]})
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], unit='s')
df = pd.concat([df]*200000).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df.head()
                 DT
2012-10-08 18:15:05
2012-10-09 18:15:05
2012-10-10 18:15:05
2012-10-11 18:15:05
2012-10-12 18:15:05

# convert the column
df['DT'] = df['DT'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam')

# display(df.head())
                       DT
2012-10-08 20:15:05+02:00
2012-10-09 20:15:05+02:00
2012-10-10 20:15:05+02:00
2012-10-11 20:15:05+02:00
2012-10-12 20:15:05+02:00

print(df.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count    Dtype                           
---  ------  --------------    -----                           
 0   DT      1000000 non-null  datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam](1)
memory usage: 7.6 MB
```

### Alternative

- This option is more concise and localizes to `'UTC'` when converting to a `datetime` `dtype` with `pandas.to_datetime()`.

```py
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam')
```

- The most time consuming aspect of the original implementation from the OP was `x['dt'].tz_localize('UTC')` within the `.apply()`
- The following code runs in about the same amount of time, within a few milliseconds.

```py
df['DT_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam')
df['DT_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], unit='s', utc=True).apply(lambda x: x.tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam'))
```

### `%%timeit` Testing

- 1M rows
- This tests the comparable vectorized version, against the version with `.apply()` from the OP, where `'DT'` has already been converted to a `datetime` `dtype`.

```py
%%timeit
df['DT'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam')
[out]:
4.4 ms ± 494 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df.apply(lambda x: x['DT'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Europe/Amsterdam'), axis=1)
[out]:
35.9 s ± 572 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```