# Matplotlib pcolormesh incompatibility with datetime object

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I'm processing time series from some instruments, and the numbers came in different patterns.

Sometimes I have the time as year, month, day, hour, etc., and I create the datetime array/list directly. When I print one element of the array (or list) created, I have something like this

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 6, 12, 0, 0)

2018-04-06 12:00:00
```

And when I use it with `matploblib.pcolormesh`, it works.

However, now I have the time as 'seconds since 1970/1/1'. My first try was doing this
[image]

And I can use the array `time_dt` with `plt.plot()`, but when I use it with `plt.pcolormesh()` I got

`TypeError: Incompatible X, Y inputs to pcolormesh; see help(pcolormesh)`

After checking and re-checking everything, the only difference was the way I create the datetime array using `matplotlib.dates`, I guess. When I create a time list using this

[image]

everything goes fine! In the present case, I can go this way. But in other cases I can't create the time array and must convert from the files from variable sources... I need to understand what's going on.

What's happening? What do I missing?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date

Comment: Please don't add code and data as image. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry. I don´t know how to do it with Jupyter Notebook, bringing the code and the results!

Answer (score 0):

Working further with this data... I found this other strange behavior!

I have the `time_dt`, created with `matplotlib.dates.num2date()`
and I have the `time_dt2`, created just with `datetime.datetime()`

Making a plot for the same variable with the two time arrays, I got this
[image]

So, it seems that `time_dt` and `time_dt2` are about the same.

When I do this
[image]

This is my expected result from the begging. But... when I do this
[image]

The `pcolormesh` is gone, no error! Quite weird...