# How to convert millisecond Unix timestamp to readable date?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string `1615070997520`. This is a Unix timestamp, but this is for millisecond. When I convert this to date with [converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), It gives me correct date (Saturday, March 6, 2021 10:49:57.520 PM GMT).

But with this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = int("1615070997520")
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

It gives me an error which is `ValueError: year 53149 is out of range`.

Is there any way to convert it into correct date like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms` using Python?

Comment: Divide `ts` by 1000 first: `.utcfromtimestamp(ts/1000)`

Comment: Exact dupe of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: also note: `utcfromtimestamp` can be misleading, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418

Comment: @MrFuppes  No. I am talking about a millisecond Unix time which is the length of 13, not 10

Comment: @MrFuppes  Then any alternatives you recommend? `time.time()` works finely?

Comment: Why do you think it makes a difference if you have seconds or milliseconds (or whatever) since the epoch - it's still the same *principle*, no? Then, the number of digits depends on how many units of time you're after the epoch. This is not some independent property.

Comment: `time.time()` *returns* seconds since the epoch, that's the other way 'round. If you want to work with datetime objects which you obtain from such timestamps, I recommend working with [aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) (which is *not* what `utcfromtimestamp` returns). See also [Paul's blog](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) for some background info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
ts = int("1615070997520")/1000
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```