# How to convert JSON dates in milliseconds to return readable format in Cloud Function with Python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, salesforce

I have a Cloud Function that connects to the Salesforce Bulk API with a select query that returns the data in JSON which then uploads to a Google Cloud bucket. The CF itself works with no issue, however the field with a date in it returns the date in milliseconds.

I'm looking for a way to convert this date from milliseconds to a readable datetime format.

```
def test_query():

  job = bulk.create_query_job("Person", contentType='JSON')
  batch = bulk.query(job, "SELECT Name, Id, Date FROM Person")
  bulk.close_job(job)
  while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
    sleep(10)


  for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):
    result = json.load(IteratorBytesIO(result))
    for row in result:
        print(row)# dictionary rows

  # Push data to GCS
  blob = bucket.blob('PersonObj.json')
  json_string = json.dumps(result)
  blob.upload_from_string(json_string)
```

Result of one line of JSON

```
"Name": "John Smith",
"Id": "0011E01231fAn1BWTF",
"Date": 1550602301000
```

Looking to have "Date" be returned as something readable such as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.s

Perhaps this is something that can be done using the CSV method or in BigQuery as this is ultimately where I intend to use this data.

Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.softhints.com/python-convert-date-unix-timestamp/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513597/how-to-convert-millisecond-unix-timestamp-to-readable-date (answer loses ms)

Comment: Okay, this is a bit silly. I’ve been unable to locate a true duplicate that *keeps* milliseconds; however, I’m sure such exists.

Comment: In the example value given (1550602301000), there appears to be *no millisecond* precision of interest. If there are *expected* to be millisecond information to preserve (and should be preserved), choose a different value where such could be lost when decreasing the precision. This added details may impact viable answers.

Comment: I'm more so looking for a readable date format as opposed to this long integer that I'm receiving back currently. Less concerned with millisecond precision, but instead just trying to make sense of this date.

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonBlob = {"Name": "John Smith",
"Id": "0011E01231fAn1BWTF",
"Date": 1550602301000}

datetime.fromtimestamp(jsonBlob["Date"]/1000.0)
```

Not sure if 2019-02-19 12:51:41 is the actual date due to not having actual data. Perhaps solve with above

Comment: This *loses* any milliseconds, should they appear (in this case no millisecond information was provided in the example value). This potential loss of precision should be included in such answers, as a note — Python datetime objects themselves have microsecond precision.

Comment: Specifically the OP calls out “milliseconds” in the title and shows a format of `hh:mm:ss.s`. With the truncation to seconds, this would always end as ".0".