# Convert timestamp in list with python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I get a list of data as follows. and I convert the timestamp to my own clock time as below but it gives an error.
How can I do this in a list?

```
 1617009300000
 1617009300000
 1617009300000
```

**code**

```
 candles_df = pd.DataFrame(klines, columns=['T', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
 candles_df['T'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(candles_df['T'])/1000)
 candles_df['T'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(candles_df['T'])/1000)
 print(candles_df['T'])
```

**result**

```
 raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
 TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Try `candles_df['T']).astype(int)/1000`

Comment: if you work with `pandas`, make sure to use the pandas built-ins, as @NagaKiran shows in his answer. Also note that Python's `fromtimestamp` will give you *local time* if you don't specify a time zone. If you need UTC, you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use format of seconds `unit=s` with pandas to_datetime it would work for your requirement i guess.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(a).div(1000), unit='s')
# MrFuppes inputs
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(a), unit='ms', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Moscow')
```

Out:

```
0   2021-03-29 09:15:00
1   2021-03-29 09:15:00
2   2021-03-29 09:15:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: When I do it like this, UTC difference is revealed

Comment: i thought your error is w.r.t conversion, would you clear it bit more@johnvayne

Comment: Why divide by 1000 if you can just use `unit='ms'`? And by the way, you can set `utc=True` if the OP needs that to be specified.

Comment: time difference is emerging, how can I fix it? UTC + 3

Comment: @johnvayne: to convert to a certain tz, use e.g. `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(a), unit='ms', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Moscow')`