# How do I find the date string from the numeric value?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

When I run `time.mktime(datetime.strptime("2012-03-09", "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())`

I get the value `1331251200.0`.

Now I want to know how can I invert this? So if I pass in `1331251200.0`, how do I get as output `2012-03-09`? I know strftime is the inverse of strptime, but I don't see how to invert the whole thing because of the timetable function.

Comment: From the docs, looks like it's just `time.localtime`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime

Comment: Yeah I have that now but I want a string output of 2012-03-09. Now I get `time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=69, tm_isdst=0)` as output.

Comment: Nvm I got it.
`time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime(time.mktime(datetime.strptime("2012-03-09", "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())))` is what I could do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0):

So the way to do this is by `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime(time.mktime(datetime.strptime("2012-03-09", "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())))`.

I didn't know strftime would turn the timetable to a string before I asked.

Comment: Note that datetime objects have methods `timestamp` and `fromtimestamp` - seems to me as if those would make your life easier.