# How can I use decrypt_at_time function in Fernet (Python 3.9)

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, fernet

I have a project which encrypts and decrypts texts. I am using Fernet to encrypt and decrypt. I learned how to use `encrypt_at_time` function but I didn't understood `decrypt_at_time` function. I was looked here:

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#

It says I must write `token`, `ttl` and `current_time` in the `decrypt_at_time()` function. Token is encrypted text, but I didn't understood what is `ttl` and `current_time`

I want to get the encrypted time from encrypted text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the encrypted time from encrypted text. How can I do it?

The structure of the Fernet token is, s. [Fernet Spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md):

```
Version | Timestamp | IV | Ciphertext | HMAC
```

where version is 1 byte long, timestamp 8 bytes, IV 16 bytes, ciphertext a multiple of 16 bytes, and HMAC 32 bytes.

Here the timestamp is the time in seconds elapsed between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and the creation of the token, s. [here](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#timestamp). Thus from the timestamp the elapsed time in seconds can be determined and from this the date, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682808):

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from datetime import datetime

def getCreationDateTime(token):
    timestamp = f.extract_timestamp(token)
    creationDateTime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return creationDateTime

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b'My secret data')
print(getCreationDateTime(token)) # e.g. 2021-04-28 18:29:42
```

> I didn't understood decrypt_at_time function...I didn't understood
> what is ttl and current_time

In [`encrypt_at_time()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.encrypt_at_time) with the second parameter (`current_time`) an arbitrary time can be specified as creation time of the token. Here again the time in seconds must be specified, which elapsed between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and the alleged creation time of the token. This can be easily tested with the above code by replacing the encryption with:

```
token = f.encrypt_at_time(b'My secret data', 0)
print(getCreationDateTime(token)) # 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

which sets the 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC as the creation time.

In [`decrypt_at_time()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.decrypt_at_time) the third parameter (`current_time`) can be used to specify an arbitrary time as decryption time (again as time in seconds which elapsed between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and the alleged decryption time of the token). The second parameter (`ttl`) specifies the time in seconds that the token is valid after its creation. Test:

```
token = f.encrypt_at_time(b'My secret data', 0)
plaintext = f.decrypt_at_time(token, 45, 30)
print(plaintext) # b'My secret data'
```

Here the token is supposedly created on 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, on allegedly 1970-01-01 00:00:30 UTC the decryption is performed. The token is valid because it is valid for 45s after its creation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood correctly now. Have a good day! :)