# Convert Epoch time to local time

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

**log_input.log**

```
1949,1603441909,984159,0.002608,19.8829994202,0.0,640.0
950,1603441910,  416274
21,160340, 24666082,0.002608,19.81913,0.0,638.0
```

Check the column consistency, disregard the row if the column number are not consistent. Read the second column and convert the second column into local time format.

**log_output.log**

```
1949, 10-31-49,984159,0.002608,19.8829994202,0.0,640.0
21, 9-32-20, 24666082,0.002608,19.81913,0.0,638.0
```

Code:

```
with open('log_input.txt', 'r') as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)
    csv_lines = list(csv_data)

for line in csv_lines:
  line[1] = convert(line[1].split(':')[1].strip())
```

Comment: seconds since the epoch -> "readable date" basically described in [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3682748/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert epoch to a date using datetime with:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(<your epoch>))
```

In case it is less than a day, just check if it is less than 86400, and if yes, write as-is.