# Convert timestamp object to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

```
data = [07222020051111, 07222020051058, 07222020051107]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['time'])
```

I am seeking to transform the data in the 'time' column to display as follows:

```
   time
0 2020-07-22 05:11:11
1 2020-07-22 05:10:58
2 2020-07-22 05:11:07
```

I have tried:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strptime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%m:%s')

df['time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['time'])
```

both without success.

I am very new to this so please excuse if this seems very basic.

Comment: please check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the datetime module to parse the strings into dates first then creating the dataframe using datetimes for data takes care of it.

```
    data = ["07222020051111", "07222020051058", "07222020051107"]
    data2 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%m%d%Y%H%M%S") for i in data]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['time'])
```

should do it

Comment: that was great. worked exactly how i needed. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function to convert a column to datetime type:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m%d%Y%H%M%S')
```

here's the format arg is your data's date format, and not your desired output format

Comment: this works also and is more readily fitted to my overall code since the actual example given by me required building the df from stracth, much preferable thanks