# Getting the DateTime Text in the OpenWeatherMap API in Python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, openweathermap, datetimeformatter

I'm attempting to get datetime information from the JSON I'm pulling from the API in a quick script I'm making in Python.  When I go to grab the `'dt'` value, it gives me such lovely results as `1628313960` or `1628314020`.  If you're a robot out there, I'm sure this is pretty good info, but to a human like me, I'm looking for something a little more along the lines of:

`"dt_txt": "2020-08-05 13:00:00"`

as it is showed in the API docs.  I'm not able to find this key anywhere in the dictionary I've pulled.  It does not appear to be there.  This is what I've tried:

```py
import requests, json


def get_48_hour_weather_data():

    url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={api_key}&units=metric'

    response = requests.get(url)
    weather_data = json.loads(response.text)

    return weather_data
```

Does anybody know how to either:

- Convert something like `1628313960` to something like `"2020-08-05 13:00:00"`
- Get the `'dt_txt'` value associated with the rest of this `weather_data`

Either solution would be great, and any help is appreciated!  Thank you for reading, and I hope this an easy answer or reputation point for you if you are reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable especially to record date and time, then use datetime from datetime library. ()
reportTime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(weather_data["dt"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')