# convert pandas df to json then parse dates

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime, epoch

I have a pandas df like this below with a `Time Block` index column and a `Payload` column that is an int:

```
    Payload
Time Block  
2021-08-20 00:00:00 1
2021-08-20 00:15:00 2
2021-08-20 00:30:00 3
2021-08-20 00:45:00 4
2021-08-20 01:00:00 5
```

Pandas to json, it seems to automatically convert to epoch time:

```
result = df.to_json(orient="index")
```

Looks like this:

```
'{"1629417600000":{"Payload":1},"1629418500000":{"Payload":2},"1629419400000":{"Payload":3},"1629420300000":{"Payload":4},"1629421200000":{"Payload":5}}`
```

parsing the json data:

```
import json

parsed = json.loads(result)
```

Looks like this:

```
{'1629417600000': {'Payload': 1},
 '1629418500000': {'Payload': 2},
 '1629419400000': {'Payload': 3},
 '1629420300000': {'Payload': 4},
 '1629421200000': {'Payload': 5}}
```

What I cant figure out is how do I convert the original time block column back into datetime?

For example the first date is 1629417600000, if I try:

```
from datetime import datetime


epoch_time = 1629417600000
datetime_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
```

This will throw an error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Is there anything that should be done to the Pandas time block column after the json data is parsed?

If I do:

```
import time

time.time()
```

Looks like this below a bit different that how pandas packaged my date time index to json:

```
1629571434.5085876
```

The time.time() also parses just fine too as shown below.

```
epoch_time = time.time()
datetime_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
```

Any tips greatly appreciated. Its almost like I need to divide my pandas epoch values by 1000 but I am not entirely sure how epoch time is calculated to know if this would work OK.

Comment: The time you are getting is in Unix time format. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682808/2681662

Comment: Ah thanks, whats the difference between unix and epoch time? I know epoch is a time value that can be calculated since a  date in 1970, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `fromtimestamp` takes seconds as input and you're providing milliseconds.

Dividing by 1000 is exactly what you need to do (and will work as needed). You may however need to use the `utcfromtimestamp` function instead:

- `fromtimestamp` gives you the date and time in local time
- `utcfromtimestamp` gives you the date and time in UTC.

```
from datetime import datetime
>>> [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(ts)/1000) for ts in parsed]
[datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 20, 1, 0)]
```