# Converting Unix timestamp to date time - different results for JS and Python

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, timestamp

I have sqlite log file where date is in timestamp.

The conversion with JS by following function gives the correct result

```
var unixTsToDate = function (UNIX_Timestamp){
var date = new Date(UNIX_Timestamp / 1000);
return date;
};

unixTsToDate (1615370972685000) = Wed Mar 10 2021 11:09:32 GMT+0100
```

Now I'm trying to to the same with Python 3.9 and it aborts with Error

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1615370972685000))

result:
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1615370972685000))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The number seems too big for the function. Tried with /1000 (found in internet that could be different timestamps with milliseconds and without), no result

What could be a solution for Python in the case?

Comment: Python uses seconds, while it's milliseconds that go into your JS function, so divide by 1000 in Python as well. Concerning the conversion of Unix time to UTC in Python, also note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp value has microsecond resolution.

51 years (since epoch) * 365 * 24 * 3600 will give roughly 1.6 billion seconds. Your value has additional 6 digits.

So in Python divide by 1000000 instead of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Python

```py
round(time.mktime(datetime.timetuple())
# in seconds, if you want to deliver this to frontend, multiply by 1000
```