# Formatting a timestamp to date giving wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to format a timestamp `1584474718199` to date but it gives me wrong date. This is what I'm getting `2020-03-18` at this moment whereas the correct date shhould be `2020-03-17`. How can I achive that?

My current approach:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1584474718199/1000
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(f"{dt_object:%Y-%m-%d}")
```

Comment: Wrong timezone?

Comment: The [datetime.fromtimestamp documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) says: "Return the **local** date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp". So, it seems that your timestamp is being treated as UTC, and that your local timezone is ahead of UTC.

Comment: You can simply set the tz to UTC in the fromtimestamp method, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my computer (located in PST) your code returns:

```
2020-03-17
```

Printing the hour minute and second:

```
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Returns:

```
2020-03-17 12:51:58
```

It's possible that your local timezone is causing problems, in which case you could try localizing it to UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
dt_object = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(f"{dt_object:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}")
```

Which returns:

```
2020-03-17 19:51:58
```

You might want to check your local UTC offset as well:

```
utc_offset = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
utc_offset_hours = utc_offset.seconds/(60*60) + utc_offset.days*24
print(f"{utc_offset_hours} hours")
```