# When using PYODPS, encountered Type Error: <class 'odps.df.expr.core.Column'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python

I am trying to analyze the data using pyodps, and when I tried to convert a column that represents dates from something like '1610979354783' to a readable datestamp, I got a type error saying <class 'odps.df.expr.core.Column'> is not convertible to datetime.

Can anybody help me with this issue? I am new to pyodps so I do not really know what happened.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @asnerdyasSteveWozniak  I used the code "transaction = DataFrame(o.get_table('v_f_transaction'))" to get the data frame, and then I tried to convert the variable ctime to a readable timestamp, the variable ctime is inst64 and consists of 13 numbers (one example is "1610951768198"). I tried "transaction.ctime = pd.to_datetime(transaction.ctime) and transaction['ctime']=pd.to_datetime(transaction['ctime'].map(lambda x:datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x/1000)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))), while none of them worked.

Comment: Please supplement your post by writing your attempts as formatted code for easier reading instead of posting them in a comment. This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682808/3679111