# How to convert time() to datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime, time

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

print(f'{datetime.now()} and {time()}')
```

Yield `2022-03-25 16:27:37.051854 and 1648193257.051854` 
I hope to get`datetime.now()` from `time()`.

I found `Sec: 37 = 1648193257 % 60`. 
`27469887 = 1648193257 // 60` 
`min: 27 = 27469887 % 60`

But I could not find how can yield hour data and so on.

Comment: You could convert the time-string into a datetime object with
datetime.fromtimestamp(time()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` function for it.

```py
print(datetime.datetime.now())
now = time.time()
print(now)
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now))
```

Yields

```
2022-03-25 09:13:42.665469
1648196022.6654692
2022-03-25 09:13:42.665469
```

A similar question with answers you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you review [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

As an example, you can get the current hour as follows:

```
import time

print(time.localtime().tm_hour)
```