# Transform Unix time stamp to a readable date time format

Tags: python, pandas, api, datetime, time

Im new to python and I would like to make my time column a readable date time format. My end goal is too pull yearly data for a crypto and only using Daily closes.

Kinda having trouble defining my Time column properly to transform it.

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
import json
import datetime
url = 'https://api.kucoin.com'


kline = requests.get(url + '/api/v1/market/candles?                type=1min&symbol=BTC-USDT&startAt=1566703297&endAt=1566789757')
kline = kline.json()
kline = pd.DataFrame(kline['data'])
kline = kline.rename({0:"Time",1:"Open",
            2:"Close",3:"High",4:"Low",5:"Amount",6:"Volume"},   axis='columns')

kline.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
kline.head()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` with `unit` argument

```py
kline = kline.rename({0:"Time",1:"Open",
                      2:"Close",3:"High",
                      4:"Low",5:"Amount",6:"Volume"}, axis='columns')

kline['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(kline['Time'], unit='s')
# ^^^  Addition here

kline.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Ayyyy thanks a lot man this ended up working got just what I needed in yyyy-mm-dd format