# Convert UNIX timestamp into UTC time within a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x, unix, timestamp

How can I convert UNIX timestamp into UTC timestamp and export data with UTC timestamp to csv in python? Here is my code:

```
from csv import DictWriter
orders = client.get_my_sales(symbol='AI95')
with open ('testcsv.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter (outfile, ('time', 'symbol','orderId','price','qty'))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows (orders)
```

And this is the output of print(client.get_my_sales(symbol='AI95'))

```
[{'orderId': 22153,   'price': '500.30000000',   'qty': '8.05000000','qty': '1910.26500000',   'symbol': 'AI95',   'time': 1657118024716},

{'orderId': 22153,   'price': '600.30000000',   'qty': '10.05000000', 'qty': '2040.26500000',   'symbol': 'AI95',   'time': 1657118030000}]
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076703/10197418

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```py
def convert_to_utc_from_unix(unix_time):
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(unix_time))
```

to convert an UNIX timestamp into UTC in python. It returns time in UTC like this: `2022-07-06 17:42:14`, you can change the formatting however you like for example instead of `-` you can use `/`. Just remember to `import time`.

Then after converting to UTC, get the array and replace the UNIX time with UTC and write it to your `.csv` file.