# How can I convert string date number (1656626400000+0200) to datetime in Python (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, integer, dtype

I have this date format (date integer) in a pandas column that I want to show as a datetime format (python)

"/Date(1656626400000+0200)/"
I tried pd.to_datetime() and variations but it didn't work out, someone knows the best to way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what's the number supposed to represent? Unix time? Doesn't make much sense to me to combine this with a UTC offset then?

Comment: check-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date