# python3 how to convert timestamp with timezone to int? like b'1664348567 +0000'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to change `b'1664348567 +0000'` to int and compare date.
I don't know how to convert this timestamp.

Comment: `int(b'1664348567 +0000'.decode("utf-8").split(" ")[0])` ? To convert to datetime, see [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3682748/10197418) : `datetime.fromtimestamp(i, tz=timezone.utc)`, would give 2022-09-28 07:02:47+00:00 with your example.

Comment: Note (this applies to very very few people, but), when comparing `datetime` objects the returned delta represents the number of UTC clock ticks and not the number of elapsed seconds between the datetimes. // If you want the true number of seconds you may need another library like `skyfield`(`.timelib.Time`). // For example find the delta between two datetimes on either side of a leap second event; `1999-01-01T00:00:01 UTC` and `1998-12-31T23:59:58 UTC` 3 clock tick delta but 4 seconds elapsed.