# Python: How to convert Timestamp which of precision 9 to datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am fetching crypto data from the ByBit exchange which is returning the timestamp field `created_at_e9` in the following format: `1663315207126761200`

The standard is 11 -13 digits but here are 20 digits. How do I fetch the DateTime from it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date) (just adjust the unit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime) so see how to convert a timestamp into a datetime in python. And since the timestamp presision is `1e9` you can simply multiply the value by `1e-9` or divide it by `1e9` to get the timestamp in seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(created_at_e9 * 1e-9)
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about your code, e.g. the exact problem and what you fix