# How to convert stdf time to datetime format in python

Tags: python, pandas

| SETUP_T | START_T |
| --- | --- |
| 1690308413 | 1690309037 |

I have read in a stdf file into a dataframe with pandas, but the `SETUP_T` and `START_T` columns present the time in a way that I am unfamiliar with. Is there any method to convert it to the standard datetime format?

My first reaction was to convert it from seconds to datetime (lol) but I realize it doesn't work that way. I've also tried changing the format of the cell in Excel, but I still don't get the results I need.

Comment: According to the STDF spec, the timestamps are standard Unix epoch timestamps - seconds from midnight January 1, 1970 in local timezone. Which there are several posted answers on how to convert already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) should do the trick:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"START_T": [1691477659, 1691471659]})
>>> df
      START_T
0  1691477659
1  1691471659
>>> df["START_T_DT"] = pd.to_datetime(df["START_T"], unit="s")
>>> df
      START_T          START_T_DT
0  1691477659 2023-08-08 06:54:19
1  1691471659 2023-08-08 05:14:19
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your time values are the seconds passed since 1970-01-01 (Unix epoch). You can use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) to convert this to a datetime.